# Is there any way to upgrade Artifactory v6.x.x to 7.x.x

Tags: artifactory

Is there any way to upgrade Artifactory v6.x.x to 7.x.x with trial license or without a license. So that it will be helpful to us before doing it on production.

Comment: You need to tell us what you tried, and what problems you are facing.
If you are asking general questions about how to upgrade artifactory then it's out of scope for Stack Overflow - but JFrog do have documentation on their webside.

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory